# Git authentication failed while trying to push a report to GitHub using the 'git push -u origin master' command for the first time

Tags: git, authentication, github

This is my first time setting up git. After creating a repository I want to push to GitHub, I ran the command`git push -u origin master` and after inserting my password and username, the following message appeared.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8sxK.jpg)
It's basically telling me that the authentication failed. Pls, what do I do? Thank you

I just entered the command over and over, but it still gave me the same answer.

Comment: Please read the message carefully, it says what to do.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+Support+for+password+authentication+was+removed

Answer (score 0):

It is saying

> Support for password authentication was removed

It means that you can no longer authenticate with your password. Since they removed that functionality you have to use your GitHub Personal Access token instead of password.

You can find it on GitHub site. Your Profile > Settings > Developer settings > Personal Access Token > Generate New Token and try to log in with this generated token instead of your password